# Hide Splash Screen when app is not destroyed

Tags: android, memory-management, splash-screen

I have an Android app with a splash screen for 3 secs.

Now when i open my app it opens with a splash screen.
Then if I press the Home button and again open the app by the icon, it again opens the splash screen even if I did not remove it from the memory by clearing recent app list.

What i wany is if I did not clear my recent app list, it should resume from where I left.

Help needed ☺

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to supply some code, I would guess your calling finish on the splash screen?

Comment: Yes on the onPause() I am doing a finish() else if we go back from the app home screen, the splash will again come in front. Isn't?

Comment: yup, just clarifying that its happening because you are calling finish. The app icon launches the task with your launch activity which is your splash screen, when you finish it, the app icon will relaunch it as there are no tasks containing it. I'm not certain but would adding the `noHistory` flag in the manifest work?

Comment: Where to add noHistory tag? Under application tag or activity tag?

Comment: activity attribute: `android:noHistory=true`

Comment: No brother. I did that but the same result. 